# Sum of all arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is a codewars challenge where you have to return the sum of the given arguments.

Instructions:

> Calculate the sum of all the arguments passed to a function.
>
> Note: If any of the arguments is not a finite number the function should return false/False instead of the sum of the arguments.

Here's my code:

```
def sum_all(*args):
    sum = 0

    for str(num) in args:
        if not num.isdigit():
            return False
        else:
            int(sum) += num
    return sum
```

Currently I'm getting this error:

```
File "", line 9
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error message is actually happening in two places:

Here:

```
for str(num) in args:
```

and here:

```
int(sum) += num
```

You cannot cast to string and int the way you are attempting to.

What you should do instead, is keep your iteration as:

```
for num in args:
```

Then, you can check if digit by doing this:

```
    if not str(num).isdigit():
```

Finally, when you get to summing everything, simply cast `num` to `int(num)` to handle the case if you pass something like `[1, 2, '3', 4]` (not the 3 as a string):

```
sum += num
```

So, with that in mind, your code will look like this:

```
def sum_all(*args):
    sum = 0

    for num in args:
        if not str(num).isdigit():
            return False
        else:
            sum += int(num)
    return sum
```

However, as you pointed out in your comment, there is a test case for negative numbers. This is where the above code breaks. Because, negative numbers as a string:

```
"-343"
```

Do not pass `isdigit`.

If you put this in your interpreter, it will return `False`:

```
"-343".isdigit()
```

So, with all this in mind, you can actually further simplify your code when you remove that to just have this:

```
def sum_all(*args):
    try:
        return sum(int(i) for i in args)
    except:
        return False
```

Demo:

```
print(sum_all(1,2,3,4,5))
```

Outputs:

```
15
```

Comment: On `Test.assert_equals(sum_all(76856,-32,1981,1076), 79881)`, I get the error: `False should equal 79881`

Comment: Oh. You just made me realize how this can be simplified. Updating.

Comment: That worked! But can you briefly explain to me why this solutions works compared to your old solution?

Comment: @BrianGunsel I am actually in the middle of editing to do exactly that. :) Hold up.

Comment: @BrianGunsel Updated. Let me know if it's understood.

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know isdigit() didn't work for negative numbers, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't overwrite existing functions such as sum.  Use a different variable name (e.g. `sum_`).  Second, your problem is on the `for str(num) in args` line.  This needs to be `for num in args:`, with a modification of the following line for `str(num)`.

```
def sum_all(*args):
    sum_ = 0

    for num in args:
        if not str(num).isdigit():
            return False
        else:
            sum_ += float(num)
    return sum_

>>> sum_all('a', 2)
False

>>> sum_all(1, 2)
3.0

>>> sum_all(1, 2, '4')
7.0
```

Here is an alternative approach to coding the function that uses a generator comprehension to  try and sum the arguments but returns False if it fails:

```
def sum_all2(*args):
    try:
        return sum(i for i in args)
    except:
        return False

>>> sum_all2(1, 2, '4.5')
False

>>> sum_all2(1, 2, '4')  # I argue that '4' is a string, not a finite number.
False

>>> sum_all2(1, 2)
3

>>> sum_all2(1, 2, 3.5)
6.5

>>> sum_all2(1, 2, -3.5)
-0.5
```

Comment: No idea.... Perhaps because I posted before editing the explanation. You can vote it up (-;

Comment: '4' is a digit, but you cannot add '4' to an integer.

Comment: You are correct.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Amended response above.

Answer (score 2):

You're overthinking this.  There are two parts to this to note:

- `sum` is a function that already takes in a collection and gives you its sum.
- You want to reject the collection if none of them are numeric types.

Here's a start:  this particular method will reject if none of the values are `int`.  I leave expanding this out to `float` types as an exercise for the reader.

```
def sum_or_reject(li):
    return sum(li) if all([isinstance(i, int) for i in li]) else False
```

Comment: That is not how you check type in python.  Use `isinstance(i, (int, float))`

Comment: @Alexander:  Thanks for that tip, I've corrected it.  I maintain that adding the float really should be left to the reader, though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The minimal change to make your logic run is:

```
def sum_all(*args):
    sum = 0

    for s in args:
        num = str(s)
        if not num.isdigit():
            return False
        else:
            sum += int(num)
    return sum
```

The line number in the question is misleading, and there are two issues: First, you need a variable for the iteration. Second, you need a variable for the `+=` assignment. In both cases you try to apply a cast, bust the result of that would not longer be a variable and thus cannot be used as target for the assignment.

Answer (score -1):

Likewise a minimal change to your code:

```
def sum_all(*args):
    try:
        return sum(int(i) for i in args)
    except:
        return False

print(sum_all(10,'-1',10))
```

Comment: You'll note that this response is identical to the response of two others who have already replied.

Comment: It's identical to one answer. Just checked. Well looks like great minds think alike.

Comment: It's identical to the second part of my response along with the edit made my @idjaw at approximately the same time.  You should delete your answer, as it is not adding anything new to the discussion and is merely copying what others have already contributed.

Comment: Let's not argue about this. It's a simple answer to the original authors question. And I didn't copy any other answers. We simply arrived at the same solution. I used to write my solution: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php

Which is a great resource by the way.